# GraphQL input parameter

Tags: graphql

There is JSON-object (an array of different structures) like:

```
"cells": [
  {
     "x":3,
     "y":6,
  },
  {
     "type": "shape",
     "direction": right,
  },
  ....
  {
     "a": 4,
     "b": 5,
     "c": 6,
  }
]
```

I need to save this object using graphql mutation. Whats the way to do it?

```
type A {
  x: Int!
  y: Int!
}
type B {
  type: String!
  direction: String!
}
type C {
  a: Int!
  b: Int!
  c: Int!
}

union Request = A | B | C

input InputR {
   cells: [Request!]!
}

type Mutation {
    save(cells: InputR!): InputR
}
```

I tried the following, but it doesnt work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few answers, depending on what you're looking for.

1. You can't. GraphQL doesn't have union input types (today). It was originally proposed to be an antipattern, though there are proposals making their way through the processes as of today.
2. You could just create a single input type that has all of those fields, all nullable, though that leads you to the problem of ["Anemic Mutations"](https://xuorig.medium.com/graphql-mutation-design-anemic-mutations-dd107ba70496)
3. Are you sure you want to? Those structures are so incredibly different that  it may be you're thinking about the problem from an implementation standpoint, rather than a data-architecture one.
4. If #1 & #2 aren't good enough and #3 isn't true, the "best way for today" at that point is probably just to use a JSON scalar type. It requires you pass all of that in as a single JSON-compatible string. [Here is an example of one](https://github.com/taion/graphql-type-json).

Comment: Ok, thanks! For now decided to use string for such an object.